# reading files in binary mode

Tags: c, binary, fopen

i am new to reading data from files.i tried to get the data from a text file and print them using the below code.but instead all i get is junk values.it has to type the following data

`12  13  14`

The code

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a=0;
    fp=fopen("try.txt","rb");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    long int size=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        fread(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp);
        printf("%d\t",a);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

but instead what i'm getting is the following values

```
822686257  875628851  875628851  875628851  875628851
875628851  875628851  875628851
```

i read other answers given related to fread but i still couldnt understand the problem.i'm using visual c++ 2010 express

Comment: C++ or C? This looks a lot more C then C++.

Comment: Why are you trying to read binary from a text file? That will never work. Read text from text files, read binary from binary files. First thing you need to do is understand the difference between binary and text, second thing you need to do is understand whether your file is really a text file or a binary file. Here's what to do, open your file in a text editor (e.g. notepad), can you see the numbers 12, 13 and 14? If so then it's a text file and should not be trying to read binary.

Comment: It really depends on what the data in the file is.  If it's text numbers then reading it like that won't work.

Comment: but my aim is to read a really large number of data that is available in a text file using a modification of the above program...so only i try reading it using binary mode

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() // note: int
{
 FILE *fp;
 int a=0;
 fp=fopen("try.txt","rb");
 fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
 long int size=ftell(fp); // now you got size of file in bytes
 fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);    // same as rewind(fp)
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
    fread(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp); // you read one int (sizeof(int)!=1 byte)
    printf("%d\t",a);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  getch();
  return 0; // since int main()
}
```

instead, if you want to read ints from the file you must change the number of elements you read

```
for (int i = 0; i < size/sizeof(int); ++i)
{
...
}
```

### EDIT:

When looking a bit more carefully on your values in hex a pattern can be seen

`31093231`

31 is hex for 1, 09 is hex for tab and so on, fread expects the values in the file to be in binary format, at least as you wrote it above so that 12 would be stored as 0x0001 (or whatever your endianess and size of int is) but what can be seen is the ASCII value of the value so you shouldn't use fread() instead use fgetc() instead:

```
int main() 
{
 FILE *fp;
 int a=0;
 fp=fopen("try.txt","rb");
 if ( fp != NULL )
 {
   do
   {
     a = fgetc(pFile); // read one character
     if ( a != EOF ) putchar( a );
   }
   while ( a != EOF );
 }

 fclose(fp);
 getch();
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry..but i'm still getting the same output...also it reads one element more than that is in file

Comment: is it int's in the file? in your question you wrote it is a binary file and you open and read it out as such but how was the file created, did you create it from console or with a program using e.g. `fwrite(&a,sizeof(int),1,fp);` it is always good to use a well-defined data type when writing binary, int is not such a data type since the size depends on the OS.

Comment: actually i created the file from matlab and i stored it in both .bin and .txt format.but i got the above error in using both the files

Comment: it is a kind of accepted practice that when a file has extension .txt it is a readable file e.g. with notepad/vi or whatever text editor you use, in that case reading it with fread is not the way to go, instead fgets/fgetc would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it as binary. Try this code instead:

```
int no;
std::ifstream fin("try.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::beg);
if(!fin)
{
    std::cout<<"Cannot open for reading\n";
    return;
}
while(fin>>no)
{
    std::cout<<no<<std::endl;
}
```